# What is @sun.misc.Contended annotation's value?

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

In `java-8` the new annotation `@sun.misc.Contended` appears.

There are several well written articles, which explain what it does and how to use it:

- [What is @Contended and False Sharing ?](http://robsjava.blogspot.ru/2014/03/what-is-false-sharing.html)
- [@Contended (a.k.a. JEP 142)](http://shipilev.net/talks/jvmls-July2013-contended.pdf)
- [Java @Contended annotation to help reduce false sharing](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/entry/java_contented_annotation_to_help)

But what is not explained anywhere, is what is the `value` of this annotation? I mean, for example in `java.lang.Thread` it is used like:

```
@sun.misc.Contended("tlr")
int threadLocalRandomProbe;
```

What is this `"tlr"` value? What does it influence? What will happen if this `value` will be default (empty)?

Comment: You are probably aware that anything in package `sun.misc` is *not* public API and therefor not documented. So hopefully someone has some (reverse engineered) insight.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from [grepcode.com -> Contended](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/misc/Contended.java):

> A `@Contended` field annotation may optionally include a contention group tag. A contention group defines a set of one or more fields that collectively must be isolated from all other contention groups. The fields in the same contention group may not be pairwise isolated. With no contention group tag (or with the default empty tag: "") each `@Contended` field resides in its own distinct and anonymous contention group.

The `value` is documented with

> The (optional) contention group tag. This tag is only meaningful for field level annotations.

Therefore the `"tlr"` is simply a chose group name for this `int threadLocalRandomProbe` - if you annotate a second variable with the same group tag they will be grouped together and isolated together.

Comment: So we can guess, `"tlr"` means **t**head **l**ocal **r**andom…